# Unable to store form data into session storage

Tags: javascript, html, forms, session-storage

I just started to learn JavaScript and I was trying to let user input form data and store them into session storage but I can't seem to do so. Please shed some light on this, thank you.

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("formset").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var name = $("#fullname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phonenumber = $("#phonenumber").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        sessionStorage.setItem("Fullname", name);
        sessionStorage.setItem("E-mail", email);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Phoneno", phonenumber);
        sessionStorage.setItem("Msg", message);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="formset" class="main_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ">
      <input class="contactus" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" id="fullname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input class="contactus" placeholder="Email" type="tel" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <input class="contactus" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text" id="phonenumber" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <textarea class="contactus1" placeholder="Message" type="text" id="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="send_btn" type="submit" id="submitform">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the jQuery tag to this question since you do use it? I'm writing you're solution for this problem too.

Comment: Use `Window.sessionStorage` instead of just `sessionStorage`. Unless you have assigned `Window.sessionStorage` to `sessionStorage` somewhere else

Comment: That's old school code there @codemax - Modern browsers understand the sessionStorage on their own. window.PROPERTY is only neccessary when defining you're own window variables and specific properties that have overlapping with another root object like document.

Comment: If you are just starting to learn JavaScript - why "limit" yourself with libraries such as jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you made a very small typo in your form ID attribute that you try to call from Javascript.

If `$` is not undefined in your browser inspector, you should be able to select the form by `$('#formset')` instead of `$('formset')`. Let me know if that worked. I got it working on my machine with that adjustment :-)

Another good practice to learn Javascript is to write

```js
console.log("Script entered this <FUNCTION_NAME>");
```

So I solved your problem in three seconds by doing this:

```
$(function() {
    console.log("Script finished jQuery initialization.")
    $("formset").submit(function (event) {
        console.log("Script entered submit event.");
        event.preventDefault();

        var name = $("#fullname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phonenumber = $("#phonenumber").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            sessionStorage.setItem("Fullname", name);
            sessionStorage.setItem("E-mail", email);
            sessionStorage.setItem("Phoneno", phonenumber);
            sessionStorage.setItem("Msg", message);
        }
    });
});
```

With the option 'Preserve Log' on in your inspector, you see the actual submit message in the console. Else you would be redirected after the form sumbit action and your console gets cleared.

And that's how I easily discovered the mistake. I never got the "Script entered submit event." message.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help @gregory